# Google HtmlService dialog not showing

Tags: google-apps-script, modal-dialog

I am using a HTML form to display a dialog in a Google spreadsheet, gather two pieces of information and then run some google script.  Before that script runs, I change the message on the dialog to say "Working...".  When the script finishes, I want the message to change to "Complete", but that never shows up.  I assume it has something with processing the form.  Could anyone help me debug this?  Here is the code:

```
 //Called from custom Menu 
 var html = HtmlService.createHtmlOutputFromFile('index')
  .setWidth(260)
  .setHeight(200)
  .setSandboxMode(HtmlService.SandboxMode.IFRAME);
  SpreadsheetApp.getUi().showModalDialog(html, 'Processing');

//Index.html
     <!DOCTYPE html>
    <html>
      <head>
        <base target="_top">
      </head>
      <body style="font-family: Arial, Helvetica;font-size:13px">

    <div>
      <form><b>Please enter the Begin date and End date to use for this date range.</b><br><br>
         Begin Date:<br>
        <input type="date" id="begindate" name="begindate">
        <br><br>End Date:<br>
        <input type="date" id="enddate" name="enddate">
        <br><br><input type="button" value="OK" id="submitbutton" onmouseup="writeFormData()">
        <input type="button" value="Cancel" onclick="google.script.host.close()" />
      </form>
    </div>

    <script>
      window.writeFormData = function() {
        var beginDate = document.getElementById("begindate").value;
        var endDate = document.getElementById("enddate").value;

        google.script.run
          .withSuccessHandler(dataWasWritten)
          .processForm(beginDate, endDate);
      };

      window.dataWasWritten = function() {
        console.log("Function ran.");
      };
    </script>


function processForm(beginDate, endDate) {
//this works
 var html = HtmlService.createHtmlOutputFromFile('working')
  .setWidth(260)
  .setHeight(200)
  .setSandboxMode(HtmlService.SandboxMode.IFRAME)
  SpreadsheetApp.getUi().showModalDialog(html, 'Tier Processing');

  //Where all the processing is - this works
  TierProcessing.New(beginDate, endDate);

 //This never shows up!
  var html = HtmlService.createHtmlOutputFromFile('done')
  .setWidth(260)
  .setHeight(200)
  .setSandboxMode(HtmlService.SandboxMode.IFRAME)
  SpreadsheetApp.getUi().showModalDialog(html, 'Tier Processing');
}
```

Thanks for the help!

Comment: what's in `done`?

Comment: Is the html file "index" or "Index"?

Comment: Sorry, they both are "index"...and it is working.  Here is "done":            
    `<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <base target="_top">
  </head>
  <body style="font-family: Arial, Helvetica;font-size:15px">
   Process finished successfully!  <br><br><input type="button" value="Close" onclick="google.script.host.close()" />
  </body>
</html>`

Comment: Why are you showing two dialogs in the same script function? Review the Apps Script guides to HTML communication.

Comment: I'm not showing two dialogs.  I override the content of the dialog with a different message.  I found the technique here on stackoverflow and it has worked in many other instances.  This is my first time using it with a form.

Comment: Actually you're showing 2 modaldialogs(with the first one not closing)... I'm not sure...but, you can try `document.querySelector("body").innerHTML="<p>Done!!!</p>"` assuming TierProcessing is a sync function. ..Did the console log "Function ran"?

Comment: @KelliRoddy showModalDialog runs asynchronously.  Which means the modal dialog is displayed but the function continues.  I believe an error occurs with the second showModalDialog in your processForm.  You could try { } catch(err) { } to see.

Answer (score 0):

Its not clear if working and done html files do anything but it seems a lot of unnecessary use of HTML Services.  I've put together an example that has a statusBar on index.html that may accomplish the same thing.

```
function test() {
  try {
    //Called from custom Menu 
    var html = HtmlService.createHtmlOutputFromFile('HTML_Test')
      .setWidth(260)
      .setHeight(220)
      .setSandboxMode(HtmlService.SandboxMode.IFRAME);
    SpreadsheetApp.getUi().showModalDialog(html, 'Processing');
  }
  catch(err) {
    Logger.log(err);
  }
}

function processForm(beginDate, endDate) {
  try {
    //Where all the processing is - this works
    //TierProcessing.New(beginDate, endDate);
    sleep(5000);
  }
  catch(err) {
    Logger.log(err);
  }
  return;
}

<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <base target="_top">
  </head>
  <body style="font-family: Arial, Helvetica;font-size:13px">
    <div>
      <form><b>Please enter the Begin date and End date to use for this date range.</b><br><br>
         Begin Date:<br>
        <input type="date" id="begindate" name="begindate">
        <br><br>End Date:<br>
        <input type="date" id="enddate" name="enddate">
        <br><br><input type="button" value="OK" id="submitbutton" onclick="writeFormData()">
        <input type="button" value="Cancel" onclick="google.script.host.close()" />
      </form>
    </div>
    <div>
      <input type="text" id="statusBar" readonly>
    </div>

    <script>
      function writeFormData() {
        document.getElementById("statusBar").value = "Working";
        var beginDate = document.getElementById("begindate").value;
        var endDate = document.getElementById("enddate").value;

        google.script.run
          .withSuccessHandler(dataWasWritten)
          .processForm(beginDate, endDate);
      }

      function dataWasWritten() {
        document.getElementById("statusBar").value = "Function ran";
      }
    </script>
  </body>
</html>
```